# Does D3 by default deal only with arrays as data source?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Do I always have to convert objects like this

```
{
    "2013-06-26":839,
    "2013-06-25":50,
    "2013-06-22":25,
    "2013-05-14":546,
    "2013-03-11":20
}
```

to arrays like this:

```
[
  {date: "2013-06-26", value: 839},
  {date: "2013-06-25", value: 50},
  {date: "2013-06-22", value: 25},
  {date: "2013-05-14", value: 546},
  {date: "2013-03-11", value: 20}
]
```

before putting it into charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that it depends on the specific situation. The data model of D3 assumes that there is one data element for each element you want to plot, so if you want to plot multiple points (on their own or as part of a line) for example, you will need an array-like structure if you want to use D3's data model.

You don't have to use the data model however. But then there's not really any point in using D3 at all. So to make the longer answer slightly shorter, yes in almost all cases in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer! It helped me to understand D3 approach better.